# Graph theory undirected graph, weight function, build an algorithm to minimize the sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider a connected undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and a weight function $w:E\to \mathbb{R}$. Describe an efficient algorithm for finding a connected subgraph $G'=(V,E')$ that minimizes the sum $\sum_{e\in E'} w(e)$ [notice that the subgraph must contain all of the vertices of $G$]. Explain why your algorithm works.

I've thought about it, and I'm thinking that maybe I can use Prim's algorithm? I'm not really sure.

Comment: You are basically looking for minimum spanning tree. So both Kruskal and Prim's algorithm will work

Comment: Thanks, Can you expand a little? I'm a bit confused as to why this works. Don't I have to adapt Prim's algorithm somehow?

Comment: What @QED means is that a connected subgraph on all the vertices of $G$ of minimum weight is by definition a spanning tree. Since Prim's algorithm finds a spanning tree, that is all we have to do.